# Leave page confirmation on pending request to server

Tags: feature-request, confirmation

There are certain operations like upvote, downvote and starring for which we get the visual feedback *even before* the request is sent to the server. The problem is when the tab is closed quite soon after such an operation, and before a failure notification is shown to the user, then the request is silently not honored.

In a similar situation, **GMail** asks for confirmation as shown below:

[image: GMail Confirmation Dialog]

Although I hate popup confirmations, this scenario is rare enough not to be irritating, while also being useful on occasions when it actually happens.

Answer (score 2):

I think such a popup would be extremely annoying compared to the value of making sure every vote is counted. How about adding *subtle*, non-animated, visual feedback for incomplete actions instead (for example, dimming the vote number until the new value is saved, or putting some kind of mark on the clicked button)?

Comment: Yes, a non-modal visual feedback is a good suggestion. It's already implemented for actions like adding a comment and upvoting a comment. So why not for everything?